# How to select an element with spaces in the class name in mootools

Tags: mootools

In mootools how can we select a UL with spaces in its classname.
Im using mootools 1.3.2.

Need to change the style of this UL to "block".

Comment: Class names don't have spaces in them. If you think you have one, you actually have an element with two classes.

Comment: <ul class="clean menu sec_accnt" style="DISPLAY: none">
Now How can I select the UL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names cannot have spaces. Spaces separate multiple class names.

So for an element like this:

```
<ul class="class1 class2">
```

You might use this:

```
$(document.body).getElements(".class1.class2")
```

The important thing is to have the two class selectors with no spaces between them.

Comment: This worked for me :)
The problem is I placed spaces between class1 and class2 like this ".class1 .class2"